# angularjs $state.go not redirecting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm REALLY frustrated right now. I try to change the state in my ionic app for more than 5 hours now.

Here is what I have.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('tab', {
            url: '/tab',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
        })
        .state('tab.issues', {
            url: '/issues',
            views: {
                'tab-issues': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-issues.html',
                    controller: 'IssuesController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('tab.issue-detail', {
            url: '/issues/:vertragsNr',
            views: {
                'tab-issues': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/issue-details.html',
                    controller: 'IssueDetailsController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('tab.issue-steps', {
            url: '/issues/:vertragsNr/steps',
            views: {
                'tab-issues': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/issue-steps.html',
                    controller: 'IssueStepsController'
                }
            }
        })
```

when I open the url http://localhost:8100/#/tab/issues/1/steps manually in the browser everything is fine the controller get loaded and everything works as expected.

But when I do

```
$scope.goto = function(){
      $state.go('tab.issue-steps','{vertragsNr:1}') 
    }
```

in the IssueDetailsController I see a transition and the IssueStepsController gets loaded but the view doesnt change.

I also tried to do a

```
ui-sref="tab.issue-steps({ vertragsNr: r.vertragsNr})"
```

but when I click the button nothing is happening. I see that in the source of the page an href="#/tab/issues/1/steps" gets created on the element but it doesnt change the view.

I also tried

```
.state('tab.issue-steps', {
            url: '/steps',
            views: {
                'tab-issues': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/issue-steps.html',
                    controller: 'IssueStepsController'
                }
            }
        })
```

but it still isnt redirecting.

I also tried:

```
$location.url("tab/issues/1/steps");
```

which also isnt working

I dont understand why it has to be so complicated to JUST CHANGE A SIMPLE VIEW!

I dont want any subviews in the details view. I just want to open the steps view.

Ok, to clarify, I need to load the steps view into the tabs-issues view which is the content of my tab-control and this is not working from a subview.

I made a plunker with the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/YK7Fp3vUhEPGZeYtOF9Y?p=info
strange thing is on the second click everything work on the plunker. But the code is exactly the same code as in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed in that plunker you're still referencing an old version of the framework:

```
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.5/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I would change that to the latest stable release:

```
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Then you have to fix the view `issue-details.html`. You have something like this in that html view:

```
<div class="list card" ui-sref="tab.issue-detail({ vertragsNr: r.vertragsNr})">
    ....
</div>
```

you don't really need

```
ui-sref="tab.issue-detail({ vertragsNr: r.vertragsNr})"
```

cause it's basically pushing the page back when redirecting.

Just remove it so that your view looks like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Ausgaben">
<ion-content class="padding">
<div class="list card">
    <div class="item item-divider">{{r.title}}</div>
    <div class="item item-body">
        <div>
            <div><b>Vertragsbeginn:</b> {{r.rentalBegin}}</div>
            <div><b>Objekt:</b> {{r.objekt}}</div>
            <div><b>Abholer:</b> {{r.abholer}}</div>
            <div class="list">
                <button class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="goto()" ng-repeat="m in r.machines" ng-disabled="m.abgabeDatum!==null">
                <i class="icon balanced" ng-class="{'ion-checkmark': m.abgabeDatum!==null}"></i>
                {{m.title}}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and everything should work as [expected](http://plnkr.co/edit/88TO2cMHHbOFKuRSwTEN?p=preview).

PS: I've removed `hide-nav-bar="true"` directive in the view `issue-steps.html` just to make sure that the navigation works properly. It works anyway even if you add it back.

PPS: As you might have noticed there are a few differences in the way the app looks with the new version `1.1.0` of the framework.
A few things have changed since the beta.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!!!! Thank you so much. I coppied the content of issue-details.html from an other file and NEVER seen that there is a ui-sref in there. You totally saved my day. I was pulling my hair out of the issue the the view changes and imediatly changes back. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Glad I've helped Florian. Sometimes you need to be detached to spot mistakes. When we find an unexpected behaviour we tend to start moving around things, comment and uncomment and, at some point, we loose control of the whole things. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .state("newUtilities", {
            url: "/newUtilities",
            templateUrl: "app/admin/modules/newUtility/view/newUtilities.html",
            controller: "NewUtilitiesController",
            resolve: load(['myProject.newUtilities'])
        })
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Unfortunately I need to load the view into the 'tab-issues' view which is the content of my tab-control and this is not working.